# В каком случае ставится запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Вот это моя вторая главная комната.
Вот это моя вторая, главная комната.
Вот это моя вторая, главная, комната.

Как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

***Вот это моя вторая главная комната. Вот это моя вторая, главная комната. Вот это моя вторая, главная, комната.***

Смысловых значений здесь два.

1. **У хозяина две главные комнаты** и, вероятно, много других. Тогда: ***Вот это моя вторая главная комната.*** Первую главную комнату мы уже видели. Неплохой вариант, но маловероятный.
2. **Главная комната только, увы, одна**. Но она вторая по счету из тех, которые мы осматриваем. Тогда возможны две записи: ***(1) Вот это моя вторая, главная комната. (2) Вот это моя вторая, главная, комната.***

Различаются они тем, что в первом случае определения оформлены **как однородные**, а во втором случае **второе определение уточняет первое**.

Смысловые оттенки чисто авторские: (1) вторая, которая является главной; (2) вторая, которая, **кстати**, является главной. 
**Примечание.** Чаще встречается вариант (1), а вариант (3) более характерен для распространенного определения во второй позиции.

Все три формы **разрешены у Розенталя,** например: http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_23.htm

Вопрос об отделении с одной стороны или выделении с двух сторон пояснительного определения решается в условиях контекста. Ср.: **Четвёртая, последняя** часть романа завершится эпилогом. — **Четвёртая, по-видимому последняя**, часть романа завершится эпилогом;

Answer (score 0):

Запятую уместно ставить, если элементы не связаны и равносильны:

`Вот это моя очень важная, главная комната.`

`Это добрый, интересный человек.`

Третий вариант не правильный. После `главная` нельзя ставить запятую.

Смотрим остальные варианты:

Если главных комнат две, а это вторая из них - запятую нельзя (после `вторая`). Элементы связаны - вторая из главных.

Если именно вторая из комнат главная - запятая обязательна. Элементы не связаны - просто вторая.

Смысл в таких случаях решающий.

Но учитывая то, что слово `главный` часто подразумевает что-то одно (самое важное, решающее), то правильнее поставить запятую, так как главная комната, скорее всего, одна.

После `вот это` лучше тире поставить, так как пропуск глагола.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97845/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd-----).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Обновлено................